# Video autoplay in Firefox on Mac not working

Tags: firefox, html5-video

In Firefox 53 on macOS, a simple video `autoplay` attribute isn't working. No problem in any other browser, on macOS or Windows 10. The page code couldn't be simpler:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8'>
<title>Video Autoplay</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>HTML5 Video<br>This should autoplay in all browsers</h1>
<video src='../media/wildlife.mp4' width='640' height='360' controls poster='../media/wildlife.jpg' autoplay></video>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone have any idea what the issue is? To be clear, I'm *not* talking about iOS or Android - this is a laptop/desktop issue only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I had done some tinkering in about:config, which disabled the video autoplay. A "refresh" of Firefox cured the problem.

User error. ;)